# how to change current slide shown from c# Add-in for PowerPoint

Tags: c#, powerpoint, add-in

i am trying to use c# add-in to control PowerPoint current slide (to slide both ways from IR remote) but i am stuck on the programming part for the power point add-in

so as simple as it is, im having an infinite loop waiting for serial commands on background thread (done this part), but im stuck on how to change the current slide being displayed

i'm using office add-ins -> power point 2013 add-in

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2922544/142904

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How to change the current slide being displayed?**

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application objPPT;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations objPresentations;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation objCurrentPresentation;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideShowView objSlideShowView;

private void StartPowerPointPresentation(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Open an instance of PowerPoint and make it visible to the user
    objPPT = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
    objPPT.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;

    //Open a presentation
    OpenFileDialog openDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    openDlg.Filter = "Powerpoint|*.ppt;*.pptx|All files|*.*";
    if (opendlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        //Open the presentation
        objPresentations = objPPT.Presentations;
        objCurrentPresentation = objPresentations.Open(openDlg.FileName, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
        //Hide the Presenter View
        objCurrentPresentation.SlideShowSettings.ShowPresenterView = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
        //Run the presentation
        objCurrentPresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run();
        //Hold a reference to the SlideShowWindow
        objSlideShowView = objCurrentPresentation.SlideShowWindow.View;
    }
}

private void ShowNextSlide(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Unless running on a timer you have to activate the SlideShowWindow before showing the next slide
    objSlideShowView.Application.SlideShowWindows[1].Activate();
    //Go to next slide
    objSlideShowView.Next();
}
```

This should be easy to implement in an AddIn, you may have to wire up some events in the StartUp event and then follow this example on how to use the object model to show Next Slides.

Comment: @AndrewxXx did you get it working? care to award the bounty, let me know if you need anything clarified. Cheers